# jquery.tmpl() after page refresh (jquery-mobile) not rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-templates

I am using phonegap and jquery-mobile 1.4. After refreshing the page

```
$.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
            allowSamePageTransition: true,
            transition: 'none',
            reloadPage: true
        });
        }, 1500);
```

jquery.tmpl() does not append data to the div anymore, any idea?

```
//template
$("#task_pics").tmpl(info).appendTo("#owl-demo");
```

//Update entire Code:

```
gettasks: function(info) {

    //LOADING
    App.utilities.Loading();

    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",       
        url: 'xxx',     
        data: "xxx",
        success: function(data) {

            alert(data);

            var info = JSON.parse(data);        
            $("#query_image").tmpl(info).appendTo(".refpic_");

            //SetBatchID
            var id = info.batchId;
            token.set_batchID(id);

            //template
            $("#task_pics").tmpl(info).appendTo("#owl-demo");

            //stop the ajax loder
            $.unblockUI();

            //OWL CAROUSEL
            $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
                    mouseDrag : false,
                    touchDrag : false,
                    autoPlay : true, 
                    items: 2, 
                    itemsMobile: true
            });

        }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen.", App.utilities.devNULL, "Hinweis");
                $.unblockUI();
                //if token is not valid anymore -> logout (TODO)
                $.mobile.navigate('index.html');


            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen.", App.utilities.devNULL, "Hinweis");
                $.unblockUI();
                //if token is not valid anymore -> logout (TODO)
                $.mobile.navigate('index.html');

            }
        }
    });
```

Also if I add the code into:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#microtasks", function (event) {
});
```

the tmpl() is not appending the data - after refreshing I am calling the function again, data  gets loaded but the rendering does not happen

best

M

Comment: you need to wrap it in `pagecontainershow` event to work again after reloading page.

Comment: thx - but how wrap this in pagecontainershow?

Comment: Can you post your complete code of `$("#task_pics").tmpl(info).appendTo("#owl-demo");`?